# Angular - Pass array with http post

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to pass a json array and a value with http post. The value was passed but the array not.
The value of responsesList in the javascript controller is : "[{"correct":"false","answer":"a1"},{"correct":true,"answer":"a2"}]"

javascript controller

```
function setMultiQuestion(question, responses) 
{

var jsonData = angular.toJson(responses);
var responsesList = {'object':jsonData};;

$http.post(baseUrl + "Admin/insertMultiAnswers", { question: question, responsesList: responsesList })
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
})
.error(function (data, status, header, config) {
});
}
```

MVC Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult insertMultiAnswers(MultiChoiceQuestionModel model)
{
try
{
    model.setMultiAnswer();
    Response.StatusCode = 200;
    return Content("Sucess");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.StatusCode = 500;
    return Content("Fail");
}
}
```

MODEL

```
public class answerObj
{
public bool correct { get; set; }
public string answer { get; set; }
}

public class MultiChoiceQuestionModel
{
public string question { get; set; }
public List<answerObj> responsesList = new List<answerObj>();



public void setMultiAnswer()
{
using (ATLASEntities atlasEntity = new ATLASEntities())
{
    Console.Write(responsesList.Count);
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? `var responsesList = {'object':jsonData};;`?

Comment: Where is method `insertMultiAnswers` which you are referring in js?

Comment: You can do one of two things ... keep it as a json object and add the FromBody attribute to your endpoint or convert it to a json string using json.stringify() and take it into the endpoint as a string that you can then serialize it back into an object.  I prefer the first method.

Comment: Thank you . You can see the modified code above. I included the right method.

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.toJson(responses)
```

serializes to string not to an object.
You should just do

```
responsesList: responses
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to be mapped to a list the object from the json needs to be an array.

So, if you change below

```
var responsesList = {'object':jsonData};;
```

to something like:

```
var responsesList = [{'correct':true,'answer':'Meow'}, {'correct':true,'answer':'Woof'}];
```

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you get plain array (`[]`) from `responses` and not array that is inside of string value (`"[]"`). Try this:

```
function setMultiQuestion(question, responses){

    var myObj = {};
    myObj = JSON.stringify({question: question, responsesList: responses});

    $http.post(baseUrl + "Admin/insertMultiAnswers", myObj)
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    })
    .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
    });
}
```

You might have to parse that string in your backend.